# Quick Log problem?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

$2^{(x^3)} = 3^{(x^2)}$

Solve for x

I'm pretty sure I use logs to solve this, but how? to what base? I'm kinda lost.. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $2^{(x^3)}$ or $(2^x)^{3}$? (And the same question for the other term.)

Comment: Your equation is ambiguous, I have edited it.  Please check that what I have done is what you want.

Comment: The first one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Taking logs **to any base**,
$$x^3\log2=x^2\log3\ ,$$
and therefore either $x=0$ or $x=(\log3)/(\log2)$.  Note that by the "change of base" formula, the last expression is the same no matter what base you are using.

Comment: Ooooooooooo. I understand now. I had a misconception on how to take logs to a base. :(. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take natural log
$$
2^{x^3} = 3^{x^2} \implies x^3 \ln 2 = x^2 \ln 3 \implies x^2 \left( x\ln2 - \ln 3\right) = 0 \implies x_{1,2} = 0,\ x_3 = \frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2} = \log_2 3
$$

Comment: Thank you! I had a misconception on how to change bases :(.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following facts:

1. $\log(a^{(b)}) = b\log(a)$. This is the key here (assuming $\log(a)$ exists).
2. When you raise a value to 0 power, you get a value of 1, so $x^0=5^0=1$

It is obvious that when $x=0$, the 2 sides would be equal.

Now the other possible solution, starting from:

$2^{(x^3)} = 3^{(x^2)}$

Apply the log function to both sides to get:

$\log(2^{(x^3)}) = \log(3^{(x^2)})$

$x^3\log(2) = x^2\log(3)$

assuming $x$ is not zero,

$x=\log(3)/\log(2)=1.58496250072$

Now an interesting point here would be why would get the same answer if you used another base for the log?